# extracting data from xml data type field

Tags: xml, t-sql, types, field, record

i have a field that data is stored in it with xml data type value :

```
<Inning xmlns="" ID="2866433" Company="Hamfekran">
    <Test ID="rs232lon">
        <Param Name="corel" Value="0.00000" />
        <Param Name="co2rel" Value="10.8000" />
        <Param Name="hcrel" Value="111.000" />
        <Param Name="o2rel" Value="0.95000" />
    </Test>   
    <Test ID="9" Name="CustomData">
        <param Name="TireFront" Value="3.00" />
        <param Name="TireBack" Value="2.00" />
    </Test>
</Inning>
```

How could I get a result with TSQL like this :

```
corel       co2rel        hcrel        o2rel     TireFront      TireBack
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------       
0.00000     10.8000       111.000     0.95000       3.00          2.00
```

Comment: i should get my result in the records

Comment: yesterday you have asked the same question with almost the same data, got response, and marked it as correct  . show us this time what did you try

Comment: i have several test tag in it that is distinct by id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @CocoJambo TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    XmlColumn XML NOT NULL
);

INSERT  @CocoJambo (XmlColumn)
VALUES  (N'<Inning xmlns="" ID="2866433" Company="Hamfekran">
    <Test ID="rs232lon">
        <Param Name="corel" Value="0.00000" />
        <Param Name="co2rel" Value="10.8000" />
        <Param Name="hcrel" Value="111.000" />
        <Param Name="o2rel" Value="0.95000" />
    </Test>   
    <Test ID="9" Name="CustomData">
        <param Name="TireFront" Value="3.00" />
        <param Name="TireBack" Value="2.00" />
    </Test>
</Inning>');

SELECT  a.*,
        b.c.value('(Test[@ID="rs232lon"]/Param[@Name="corel"]/@Value)[1]','NUMERIC(38,5)') AS corel,
        b.c.value('(Test[@ID="rs232lon"]/Param[@Name="co2rel"]/@Value)[1]','NUMERIC(38,5)') AS co2rel,
        b.c.value('(Test[@ID="rs232lon"]/Param[@Name="hcrel"]/@Value)[1]','NUMERIC(38,5)') AS hcrel,
        b.c.value('(Test[@ID="rs232lon"]/Param[@Name="o2rel"]/@Value)[1]','NUMERIC(38,5)') AS o2rel,

        b.c.value('(Test[@ID="9"]/param[@Name="TireFront"]/@Value)[1]','NUMERIC(38,5)') AS TireFront,
        b.c.value('(Test[@ID="9"]/param[@Name="TireBack"]/@Value)[1]','NUMERIC(38,5)') AS TireBack
FROM    @CocoJambo a
CROSS APPLY a.XmlColumn.nodes('/Inning') AS b(c)
```

References:

[The XML Methods in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-xml-methods-in-sql-server/)

[nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx)

[value() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)

[xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx)